# Setting https proxy for e2e-tests in Protractor

Tags: node.js, selenium, proxy, webdriver, protractor

I would like to stub network requests to third-party services during e2e-tests with Protractor while keeping the communication between the browser and my api. Also, I want to be able to stub some specific calls to my api while keeping other calls intact.

The application I am testing is containerized into Docker containers. e2e tests are run in Firefox in one container, while the API server is in another one.

So what I am trying to do is set up a container with a proxy Node server (let’s call this container `proxy`). I want all the network traffic from the browser to pass through the proxy server, where a part of that traffic can be stubbed as necessary.

This almost works. However, what I observe is that only the `http` traffic gets passed through the proxy whereas the `https` traffic escapes the proxy. I wonder why this may be happening.

Here is the relevant part of Protractor config:

```
exports.config = {

    ...

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'proxy': {
            'proxyType': 'manual',
            'httpProxy': 'proxy:3000',
            'sslProxy': 'proxy:3000'
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

I tried both the `sslProxy` and the `httpsProxy` options, like I saw in various online discussions, but none helped direct https requests through my proxy. For example, I added two images on a page — one of Google logo served via http and the other served via https. I can see in the `proxy` docker logs that the request for the image served via http gets passed through the proxy server, but the request for the image served via https doesn’t.

So my question is, is there something obviously wrong that I am doing? Could you suggest whether it’s possible to direct browser’s https requests through the proxy server as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capability for `proxy` does not appear to be currently supported in [protractor reference config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143038/setting-https-proxy-for-e2e-tests-in-protractor).

Instead of trying to redirect your calls to the proxy server via protractor or possibly `/etc/hosts` file, you might want to consider changing the web application to have a dependency injection to change those calls to point from your third party server to the proxy server.

Comment: Interesting. Well, the `httpProxy` part of the proxy capabilities works anyway. It's sad the `httpsProxy` part doesn’t.

Thank you for the explanation and for the suggestion.